# UDPClient in VB.net

Tags: python, vb.net, udpclient

I have the following code for sending an UDP command to a program. it works fine in Python and the program responds to this command.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 15650))
s.send('RU')
```

I wanted to use a GUI program, so I made a VB.net program with the following code. But it does not work.

```
Dim udpClient As New UdpClient()
udpClient.Connect("localhost", 15650)
Dim bytCommand As Byte()
Dim pRet As Integer
bytCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RU")
pRet = udpClient.Send(bytCommand, bytCommand.Length)
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Comment: The program (server) does not receive the data. Though the VB appears to be sending the data.

Comment: Doesn't python use UTF8 encoding by default ... you want to change your encoding to bytCommand = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("RU"), or can you see that the bytes aren't getting to the server at all ?